# Где правильнее хранить базу данных?

Tags: sql-server, сервер, хостинг, openserver, hosting

Собираюсь писать приложение для магазина. Естественно в нем будет Бд MySql. Бд нужна НЕлокальная. Прочитал множество материала, но в голове не однозначный ответ.

Мне нужно поместить Бд на хостинг или сервере?
Я понимаю, что сервер - это отдельный, мощный пк, который может стоять где угодно, но хостинг это как бы частичка сервера, на котором размещают сайты, на которых также используют Бд. Как я понял, для сайта используется локальная Бд, которая хранится на хостинге, тоесть по сути для сайта она будет на одном пк. А мне нужен виртуальный сервер, который мне даст ip, port,host, и т.д. через которые я уже и буду подключаться? Или я что-то неправильно понял?

Приложения с уже созданными Бд уже писал , а теперь возникла потребность сделать все самому и с нуля.

Comment: Если это просто "поиграться" в магазины, то нет смысла сервер покупать, проще и дешевле хостинг взять, при покупке которого вам выдаются все нужные данные, в т.ч. и данные для подключения mysql

Comment: @InDevX, нет, это именно проект. Но там не будет сверх большого объёма данных. До 1 Гб. Разница в сервере и хостинге в моем случае получается только в цене? И можно купить как 1е так и 2е?

Comment: Не в объемах данных дело. Если магазин не требователен к ресурсам и без огромной посещалки то можно взять хостинг, если же нагрузка более-менее приличная (в плане посетителей, что, так же, будет влиять на серверную нагрузку), много запросов в БД и пр. атрибуты тяжелого проекта, надо надёжно хранить данные и пр. то лучше брать сервер

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Теперь в моей голове чёткий ответ.